# Implementation of Word2Vec in Non-English Based languages?

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, stemming, lemmatization

Is it possible to implement Word2Vec models in languages which isn't based on the English alphabet like Urdu, Tamil etc? If so can someone suggest me a pathway.

Comment: just preprocess the data and convert it into numberized format, create a dictionary (word,id). Then pass the numberized file to word2vec. You will be set to go. Just in the query time take your input, use the dictionary and convert it to numberized version before passing it to the trained model!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think it should be possible, provided you have a tokenizer (i.e. word splitter) for your language, and possibly a lemmatizer or stemmer if you have smallish data and want to replace inflected word forms with some base form representation.

Here's a basic example for training a model with gensim in Python:

```py
from gensim import models

training_corpus = "corpus.txt"

with open(training_corpus,'r') as f:
    plain_text = f.read()

sentences = plain_text.split("\n")  # Assume one sentence per line
tokenized = []

for sentence in sentences:
    # White-space-based word splitting, replace with a better tokenizer
    tokens = sentence.strip().lower().split(" ")
    tokenized.append(tokens)

# Train your model, see gensim documentation for parameters
model = models.Word2Vec(tokenized, min_count=3, size=50)
```

Comment: giving it a try.